# adding data to a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a tableview filled with conversations meaning each cell has a persons name on it and when you click that persons name it sends an object containing the latest message to another view controller and segues to it so you can see the message.  If i want to reply and send that reply back to that specific cell i click on how do i do it?  Im using the cell identifier as the persons name that is displayed on the cell.

Basically i want to know how to store a new object or property in a specific cell using the cell identifier.

Comment: First off, using a person's name as the identifier is bad. What happens if you have two people whose names are John? Use userIDs instead as they are guaranteed to be unique. Second you just add the reply back in the conversation object you're sending down to the VC. On viewWillAppear of your tableView, you should be reloading the cells to show the latest response in each cell, so this will be handled automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with LyricalPanda. You need a better unique identifier than a name. Where is your data coming from? Does it have something unique? If not you need to create one when you load your data source and before you show it.

Comment: Yes LyricalPanda was definitely right.  I've generated a random conversationId, and I am currently using that as the cell identifier.